# The shell command for sending email does not work in python subprocess call

Tags: python, shell, email

I use a mail command in shell to send email:

```
echo "abc" | mail -s "Subject" abc@def.com
```

I want to use this command in python, so I write the following:

```
call("echo abc" "|" "mail", "-s Subject", "abc@def.com", shell=True)
```

Then it gives me the following error:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 7, in <module>
    call("mail", "-s", "Subject", "abc@def.com", shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 629, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call a `call` method like this

```
call(["mail", "-s", "'Subject'", "abc@def.com"], shell=True)
```

Part 2:

```
sudo touch /var/mail/<username>
sudo chown <username>:mail /var/mail/<username>
sudo chmod o-r /var/mail/<username>
sudo chmod g+rw /var/mail/<username>
```

taken from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1500892)

Comment: I should actually type this: call(["mail", "-s Subject", "abc@def.com"], shell=True). But it gives another error: 
Cannot open mailbox /var/mail/rex: Permission denied

Comment: So your now method call is correct. What gives this this command when you run it from the and shell the *same* user. Are the privileges to this */var/mail/rex* are ok?

Comment: Yes. Shell has no problem.

Comment: I updated the question. To avoid subtle issues, I add echo in the shell to pass in the content of the email. Because if I do mail directly, it will pop up prompt for me to type in CC and content. But the problem remains. Shell works fine, but python gives me the permission error.

Comment: please provide the output of call(['whoami'],shell=True) and (from shell) ls -lah /var/mail/rex

Comment: did $sudo chmod aug+rw /var/mail/rex help? (this is not good soulution, just to understand the problem)

Comment: I did $sudo chmod aug+rw /var/mail/rex. It gives "No mail for rex". Which does not appear when I type the same command in shell. And the mail is not sent either.

Comment: But the privilege problem is gone.

Comment: ok. I will ask the privilege problem in another post. Thank you!